# Set value of Popup LOV with dynamic action

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I try to set the value of a popup lov with a dynamic action "Set value" of type PL/SQL Function Body. This works with a select list, but not with a popup lov. How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume your item is P1_ITEM and your LOV is

```html
select display, return from table;
```

In standard Select List value is stored in #P1_ITEM.

In Popup LOV value is stored in #P1_ITEM_HIDDENVALUE, but displayed in #P1_ITEM.

So in dynamic action, you need to set two actions:

1. Set value 'return' from LOV with affected item P1_ITEM.
2. Execute JavaScript code

```html
$("#P1_ITEM").val(display)
```

Comment: And there still isn't a better way... I wonder when will they change that

Answer (score 0):

`$('#P1_ITEM').val(&display.)`

where display is the name of the field in SQL.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

This honestly worked the best for me. And was so simple! All you need to do is **apex.item('P1_PAGE_ITEM').getValue([1])**

It's as simple as using apex.item getValue and rather than () you need to use ([])